# Swipe to delete not working in iOS 8 on XCode 7 Beta

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

Im struggling to implement swipe to delete on my uitableview on ios 8 and xcode 7.

I have the following code:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    editingStyle = UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {

        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

        [_newsArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
}
```

Swiping does nothing.

I cannot test this in Xcode 6 as I am using features that are new in 7 and my project doesn't open in 6 now.

Thanks

Comment: Although you can setup a tableView in Xcode 6 in a new project and enable the editing features. Works find for me. Test a dummy project in Xcode 6 and ensure you aren't missing anything and this is in fact an Xcode 7 bug... also check your version of Xcode 7. Also, check your datasources and delegates to ensure you rigged them up to your tableView properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you can setup a tableView in Xcode 6 in a new project and enable the editing features. Works find for me. Test a dummy project in Xcode 6 and ensure you aren't missing anything and this is in fact an Xcode 7 bug... also check your version of Xcode 7. Also, check your datasources and delegates to ensure you rigged them up to your tableView properly.

Comment: Seems to be a bug in XCode 7...as swiping constantly eventually ends up in the delete button showing. Sometimes it takes 3 swipes, sometimes 20! Annoying.

Comment: Sounds like you might have something intercepting touch events

Comment: Typically, if a gesture works one out of X amount of times, it's due to something interfering with it receiving it's calls like a view with touches disabled, a view that absorbs touch events, another gesture  that absorbs events, etc. something is probably absorbing these touch events. I'm 100% positive this isn't an xcode 7 bug and can probably be replicated with the same setting and configurations in xcode 6.

Comment: The only other touch gesture is a reveal menu which is a right swipe, not a left swipe. Any suggestions?

Comment: That could do it, disable that gesture and see

Comment: Yeah seems to have done it. Thanks. Any solution to this?

Comment: You should review the documentation for UIGestureRecognizer. Note calls such as cancelsTouchesInView and requireGestureRecognizerToFail and such. Another alternative is to use another menu library such as MFSideMenu. Also, don't forget to accept my answer if I've answered the question above.